# how to programmatically set unpublish_on

Tags: 7, entities

How can I programmatically set the unpublish_on field(scheduler module) for a node entity in drupal 7?

```
$entity = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
$entity->language(LANGUAGE_NONE);
$entity->title = 'My Title';
$entity->body->set(array(
    'value' => $body,
    'summary' => $summary,
    'format' => 'full_html',
  ));
$entity->scheduler_settings->set(array(
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#unpublish_on' => '2018-06-25 12:23:11',
    '#date_format' => 'd.m.Y H:i:s',
  ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the examples set by the scheduler module when it [loads](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/scheduler/blob/7.x-1.x/scheduler.module#L454), [inserts](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/scheduler/blob/7.x-1.x/scheduler.module#L611), and [builds the form](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/scheduler/blob/7.x-1.x/scheduler.edit.inc#L16). Add the `unpublish_on` property to the node object with the value of the UNIX timestamp (of when it will unpublish). When the node is saved, the scheduler module will save the unpublish date.

```
$node = node_load(123);
$node->unpublish_on = strtotime("2018-06-25 12:23:11");
node_save($node);
```